# Why can’t I resize and position my dynamic dialog (with no XML associated)?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have studied many questions and answers in *Stackoverflow*, then I made a dummy function, that I run after a click in my app.

Here is the code:

```
fun openDialog(cx: Context) {
   val alertDialog = Dialog(cx)   
   var linLayout = LinearLayout(cx)   
   linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

   // Set width, height and weight
   linLayout.layoutParams  =  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500,1000,1F)

   // top and left position
   linLayout.x = 0F 
   linLayout.y = 0F

   val title = TextView(cx);  // dummy view 1
   title.setText("Custom Dialog 1")
   title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
   title.setTextSize(20F)
   linLayout.addView(title)  // add in layout

   val msg =  TextView(cx)  // dummy view 2
   msg.setText("Custom Dialog Box 2")
   msg.setTextColor(Color.RED)
   msg.setTextSize(10F)
   linLayout.addView(msg)   // add in layout

   alertDialog.setContentView(linLayout)  // Add the layout in Dialog
   alertDialog.show();        // Show the dialog with layout
}
```

What I get? A proper dialog, but in the middle of the screen with width and height defined by the content. I also try to use the windows linked to the custom dialog without success.

```
val wlp = win.attributes
wlp.apply {
  x = 0
  y = 0
  height = 1000
  width = 500
}  
win.attributes = wlp
```

No changes.  However `wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM`  works, but it's not enough for me. A also try to use `win.setLayout(1000,500)` without success

The Android documentation states:

> Set the width and height layout parameters of the window. The default
>   for both of these is MATCH_PARENT; you can change them to WRAP_CONTENT
>   or an absolute value to make a window that is not full-screen.

Why can’t I resize and position the layout that I assign to my dialog?
Has somebody a hint?

The cell phone screen:

[image: Phone screen]

**Update**

I've got to change the position of dialog  using

```
wlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.LEFT
wlp.x = 100  // Relative to left
wlp.y = 200  // relative to top
```

I keep trying to figure out how to change the width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the layout params for the view you're inflating when you set the content :

this line :

`alertDialog.setContentView(linLayout)`

should be :

`alertDialog.setContentView(linLayout, LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500,1000,1F))`

You can also remove the explicit setting of the params for the `LinearLayout`

Comment: It has worked. Amazing! Not in 1,000 years I would imagine that.

Comment: glad it worked, sometimes it's worth exploring overloaded methods and checking what parameters it takes, along with the associated documentation.